# Altering LED Color in MFC Dialog based on pass/fail return

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm looking for a method to give the user visual feedback as to whether a calibration has passed or failed using an MFC dialog window. I would like to have 2 "LEDs": one red (failed) and one green (passed). When the test is finished, it will pass either a "pass" or "fail" value back to the main and light up the corresponding LED.

One method that I was considering is using two images (one "unlit" and one "lit") for each LED and then switching between the two through a picture control CStatic. However, I'm not really sure how to implement this into code since I'm very inexperienced with MFC, and I'm looking for any help or suggestions you might be able to give me. Essentially, it should look something like:

```
if (RunTest(void))
{
    //Replace IDB_RED_OFF with IDB_RED_LIT
}

else
{
    //Replace IDB_GREEN_OFF with IDB_GREEN_LIT
}
```

Where IDB_XXX represents the bitmap image resource. Or if you have a better way to do it, I'm all ears.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct. You can use MFC's CBitmapButton class to draw the bitmap button. Here is how to do it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb931337

You will probably want to handle transparency as well. I don't remember exactly but CBitmapButton probably supports it. Alternatively you will have to use class like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/57/CButtonST-v-MFC-Flat-buttons

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to have *two* static image controls in the same location, and make one visible while you hide the other. You can do this with [`CWnd::ShowWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72szh9c7.aspx) using the `SW_HIDE` and `SW_SHOWNA` parameters.